# Error in Mysql Query while registering through Android App

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(name,surname,age,username,password) 
VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";
```

In this query i got an error while registering through android application **Error:Insert into candidates (name,..........)**

Comment: show your query statement and table structure

Comment: $mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(name,surname,age,username,password) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";

Comment: Table Structure:-    id  name  surname  age  username  password

Answer (score -1):

In your query column name "name" & "password" are keyword in mysql

Wrap it with `backtick` to escape keyword and it will solve the issue

```
$mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(`name`,surname,age,username,`password`) 
VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";
```

Or You can use like below

```
$mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(Candidates.name,surname,age,username,
Candidates.password) 
VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";
```

Comment: $mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(`name`,surname,age,username,password) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";

Comment: @AviralGarg u done the solution only for name..u need to apply for password too

Comment: Sir if i applied this to all as:- $mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(`name`,`surname`,`age`,`username`,`password`) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')"; also if for only name and password same error.Please help.

Comment: I also appplied:- $mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(Candidates.name,surname,age,username,Candidates.password) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";

Comment: Please suggest something @Sachu

Answer (score -1):

change `$result=mysqli_query($link,"mysql_qry");` to 
`$result=mysqli_query($link,$mysql_qry);` then try.

Comment: can you put a full code? so I can understand what is the problem.

Comment: This is Register.php file:-    <?php
require "conn.php";
$link=".............";
$name=$_POST["name"];
$surname=$_POST["surname"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$userpass=$_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry="insert into Candidates(Candidates.name,surname,age,username,Candidates.password) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$userpass')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $mysql_qry);
if($result === TRUE ){
 echo "Insert Successfull";
}
else
{
 echo "Error"  .$mysql_qry. "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>

Comment: This is conn.php File:-<?php
$db_name="candidates001";
$mysql_username="username";
$mysql_password="password";
$link="...........";

$conn = mysqli_connect($link, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

?>

Comment: PLease suggest something @Jenis Kasundra

Comment: Make sure that the HOST name($link) is proper.